# alphanumerical sequence Correct one

Tags: number-sequence, combinatorics

I have tried to solve this sequence which, I suppose has been created from the combination of a,b,c,d,e. I've reposted the correct sequence

The sequence:

> **(a,c), ?, ?, ?, (a,e), ?, ?, (c,d), ?, (b,a)**

**My logic:** We just try to do all the possible combinations :

**(A,B) (A,C) (A,D) (A,E)**

**(B,A) (B,C) (B,D) (B,E)**

**(C,A) (C,B) (C,D) (C,E)**

**(D,A) (D,B) (D,C) (D,E)**

**(E,A) (E,B) (E,C) (E,D)**

OR:

**(A,A) (A,B) (A,C) (A,D) (A,E)**

**(B,A) (B,B) (B,C) (B,D) (B,E)**

**(C,A) (C,B) (C,C) (C,D) (C,E)**

**(D,A) (D,B) (D,C) (D,D) (D,E)**

**(E,A) (E,B) (E,C) (E,D) (E,E)**

I suppose we should find the criteria with which my friend selected the items made of 2 letters.

Comment: Are any of **(E,A) (E,B) (E,C) (E,D) (E,E)** allowed?

Comment: @WeatherVane they could be allowed, or atleast i think they are allowed becasue there's letter e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My thoughts here are ...

> **(a,c)** (c,e) (e,d) (d,a) **(a,e)** (e,b) (b,c) **(c,d)** (d,b) **(b,a)**

Why this sequence?

> The pairs I've listed connect each point in A B C D E to every other point exactly once.

Huh?

> Put the letters A to E evenly spaced around a circle.
>  Each pair of letters in the sequence can be taken as one leg of a journey amongst those 5 points.
>  Follow the path, first from A to C (the first pair). Continue with the other pairs in order.
>  The sequence covers all paths between letters, in a continuous route, without retracing any edge.
>  The result is a fully connected graph for the 5 points, starting and ending at A,
>  and looks like a 5 pointed star inscribed within a regular pentagon:
>  [image]
>  For the predefined pairs given initially, I believe my solution is the unique sequence that does this.

Comment: I'm sorry could your explain your solution to me(I Think I'm stupid),I've understood that there are 5 points from where your start but i don't understand how you selected them and how you "Move" to other  groups of letters . thank you for your time  @Rubio

Comment: Nice answer: a circular journey too.

Comment: @ade Expanded explanation added to the answer now.

Comment: How did u think a solution like that xD @Rubio

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

> There are 10 items in the sequence.
>  There are 10 permutations of the letters **a** ... **e** taken in pairs.
>  There are no repeated pairs used.
>
>  So I guess that the 6 missing combinations should be used to fill the 6 gaps
>  **(a,d) (b,c) (b,d) (b,e) (c,e) (d,e)**
>
>  However the puzzle shows the pair **(b,a)** is in reverse order.
>  I was hoping that maybe the pairs in the even-numbered positions are reversed.
>  But that is not the case.